# Get follower List with userID Instagram

Tags: ios, json, web-services, instagram, instagram-api

How can I get Following/Followers List with UserID rather than "self" using Instagram API, the service for getting list of follows for current instagram user logged in and it works

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

I try to modify self with an ID of Instagram User

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/6675420875/follows?access_token=XXXX
```

but without success,the response is:

```
{
"meta": {
    "code": 400,
    "error_type": "APINotAllowedError",
    "error_message": "you cannot view this resource"
    }
}
```

this user "6675420875" already invited and added in sandbox mode.

I know the supported Api of Instagram doesn't support this anymore since June 16 but is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get followers/following for any user other than logged in users anymore, As of June 1 2016, you can only get followers/following of `self` and also only if you have been approved permission for `following_list` before Oct 1 2017.