# Instagram API facing error

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

This is my code for Instagram API which I referred in some *github*. But I'm getting error while running on jupyter notebook using python language.

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
access_token = "6784563950.xxxxxxx.32e0d729b8c741508fbbcba17f8a7e57"
client_secret = "863bb1767xxxxxxx34861c31efe54104ae"
api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token, client_secret=client_secret)
recent_media, next_ = api.user_recent_media(user_id="67xxxx3950", count=10)
for media in recent_media: print(media)
```

I'm getting error

> "C:\Users\Balaji\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\instagram\models.py in
>   object_from_dictionary(cls, entry)
>            97         new_media.comment_count = entry['comments']['count']
>            98         new_media.comments = []
>       ---> 99         for comment in entry['comments']['data']:
>           100             new_media.comments.append(Comment.object_from_dictionary(comment))
>           101 
>        KeyError: 'data'.

Can anyone help me with proper code? If I write print media it says put parenthesis.

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language you're using, and remove the irrelevant tags: `twitter-bootstrap` `facebook`

Answer (score 1):

Official client is deprecated since June 2016. Use a forked and maintained client like: https://github.com/MabrianOfficial/python-instagram
To install it `pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/MabrianOfficial/python-instagram`

Comment: thanks. but actually it didnt work. Later somehow it started working when i reinstalled anaconda.

Comment: Instagram has closed ithis endpoint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676684/get-follower-list-with-userid-instagram